# Which notation is correct

Tags: notation

This one:
\begin{align}
V &= 100 + 1 \\
 &\cong 100 \\
 &\cong 50+50
\end{align}

or

\begin{align}
V &= 100 + 1 \\
 &\cong 100 \\
 &= 50+50
\end{align}

Comment: Both are technically correct, since $x\approx x$ is a correct statement.

Comment: I like the second more even if the first is correct also... and would use $\approx$ (\approx) rather than $\cong$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no universal convention: Both the notations you described are used. Your reader will understand both, so you can pick the one you are more comfortable with (but be consistent). If you have a multiline relation like
$$\begin{align}A &\approx B\\&\approx C\end{align}$$
there are two ways to interpret the second line:

- As an *omission*: The left hand side is omitted because it's unchanged.
  $$\left\{\begin{aligned}A &\approx B\\&\approx C\end{aligned}\right\} \overset{\,\,def}{\iff} \left\{\begin{aligned}A &\approx B\\A&\approx C\end{aligned}\right\}$$
  Because you align the lines at the relation this makes sense formally (to me), but hides information about the relation between $B$ and $C$ (e.g. is $B \approx C$ or even $B = C$?). Your reader has to figure that out by himself.
- As a *continuation*: For reasons of presentation you had to add a linebreak, but the second line continuous the first.
  $$\left\{\begin{aligned}A &\approx B\\&\approx C\end{aligned}\right\} \overset{\,\,def}{\iff} A \approx B \approx C \iff \left\{\begin{aligned}A &\approx B\\B&\approx C\end{aligned}\right\}$$
  I personally find that the alignment doesn't make much sense here. On the other hand the relation between $B$ and $C$ is explicit now, which simplifies the reading.